# Stateful object from IoC

Tags: oop, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

on current project we try to get service using constructor, e.g.:

```
public class FirstService {

   private SecondService _second;

   public FirstService(SecondService second) {
        _second = second;
   }

   public void DoSomething() {
        _second.PublicProperty = "some value required by service to work properly";

        _second.DoWork();
   }        

}
```

Important part is setting the public property before calling the public method DoWork().

**Is it a good practice set required properties before we call method. Shouldn't be service constructed with everything already in place?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed poor design.  Either "PublicProperty" should be a parameter to the DoWork method, *or* PublicPropery should be set by the container.

Answer (score 0):

Most IOC containers have the ability to configure default values.. so perhaps you can configure yours for a default value and only modify when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is called "temporal coupling". You expect two actions to be called in certain order and bad things happen when they are called in wrong one.

Use **DoWork(PublicProperty prop)** instead.

Injected services should be stateless or have one setup upfront, in constructor mostly. Do not let your services float around in uninitialised state.

Comment: I answered this for future myself!